# Regex to match ">" in HTML

Tags: html, regex

I need a regex which matches ">" character in a HTML string, but doesn't match tag's closed bracket.
Example:

<span id="bla"> bla bla **a > b** bla bla bla <a>bla </a> </span>

The regex should match the ">" between **a** anb **b**

Comment: That's not HTML; it's gobbledygook.

Comment: What @SLaks said. Plus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: no, this is a kind of a bad formed HTML and instead &gt; there is ">"

Comment: @Matt, @CFreak: Regex will work fine for this.  All you need to know is whether you're inside a start/end tag.

Comment: Which regex flavor are you using?

Comment: @SLaks: by "inside," do you mean "between?"

Comment: @Matt: No; why would I mean that? _All_ content is between tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind: `(?<!\<[^>]+)\>`.
*<strike>Un</strike>**tested***

This will match any `>` character that isn't preceded by the beginning of an HTML (a sequence starting with `<` and not containing `>`)

Comment: You were just a little faster than my answer; I shouldn't be so wordy.

Comment: @zav: .Net supports negative lookbehind; Javascript doesn't.  In .Net, this does work.  Paste the following into LINQPad: `Regex.Matches(@"<span id=""bla""> bla bla a > b bla bla bla ><a<>bla </a> </span>", @"(?<!\<[^>]+)\>")`

Comment: I was constructing this regex an hour and tested them by means of this tool. I didn't know about this issue in javascript. Thanks a lot!! It does work.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work:

```
([^/]>)+
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a regex that finds "unpaired" greater-than signs; >s that are not preceded by a < as you'd find in a tag.

Try this: `"(?<!\<[^<>]+)\>"` It should match a greater-than that is not part of an HTML tag; that is, a construct consisting of a less-than, some number of characters other than the angle-bracket characters, then a greater than.

EDIT: put in SLak's suggestions. I'll keep the < in the "not match" block just in case the less-than being matched is also not part of a tag, for instance << or <-. It shouldn't hurt the pattern's ability to match proper tags.

Comment: You don't need to exclude `<` in the tags, and you don't need to escape the contents of an  `[]` block (except for `-`)

Answer (score 0):

A specific solution rather than just an admonition:

"*Beautiful Soup won't choke if you give it bad markup. It yields a parse tree that makes approximately as much sense as your original document. This is usually good enough to collect the data you need and run away.* " - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Don't use regex to parse html -

"*Among programmers of any experience, it is generally regarded as A Bad Idea to attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions.*" - [Link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

and "*You can't parse [X]HTML with regex*" - [4352 votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) at the time of this posting

"*Parsing HTML is a solved problem. You do not need to solve it. You just need to be lazy. Be lazy, use ...*" something designed for that purpose.

Comment: @Slaks - how do you go about reading a string containing html without it being called parsing?

Comment: I'm not parsing HTML. I'm correcting it to be parsed with HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Parsing means creating a structure (eg, a DOM tree).  He's just searching for characters.

Comment: @zav: Are you sure HAP can't handle this already? If it can't, it should.

Comment: That's not what this article implies to me - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing

Comment: @SLaks - How do you get to the plain text inside a tokenized string without parsing? just because it's not a proper or strict exception throwing operation doesn't mean it's not parsing.

Comment: @SLaks,Zavolokas concerning this not being parsing... the first sentence of the html agility pack's purpose is "This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM" - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: At least the version I have throws an exception